# Support for h264 codec, Open Suse

Tags: opensuse, codec

```
14:37 boffi@localhost:~ $ mpv Inaugurazione\ Cortile.mp4 
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1920x1080 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
[ffmpeg/video] libopenh264: libopenh264.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: libopenh264.so.7 is missing, openh264 support will be disabled
Could not open codec.
Decoder init failed for libopenh264
Failed to initialize a decoder for codec 'h264'.
Video: no video

Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

My guess, I need to install something, my questions:

- is h264 supported in Suse Tumbleweed?
- what package(s) need I to install to support h264?

PS, `zypper search openh264` gives `"No matching items found."`

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://www.opensuse-community.org/)?

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity That repo is a bit confusing, but I looked at the XML file for KDE and searched for 264 to no avail.